# GAE + OpenERP Store integration

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached, google-cloud-datastore, odoo

I want to develop web store on GAE, that takes data directly from OpenERP via XML-RPC.

When adding a new order as soon as there is no problem to send it to the OpenERP. But what about to get data of many products from OpenERP in real time, I'm think it is can be slow in high load. **Will there be enough to use memcached, or better put products from OpenERP into gae db?** In the latter case, I think it would be difficult to organize synchronization. Any advice?

I'm know about Django-zook, but we using OpenERP instance and we cannot install zook plugin in openerp.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't said much about your application, but caching the products in Google app engine sounds like a good strategy.